# How to debug react application built with webpack in visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack

I am totally new to react and I want to debug my application using visual studio code.

This is what I have done.

- I install visual studio code
- Add Chrome Debugger extensions.
- Add launch.json

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", 
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///*": "*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
                "meteor://app/*": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I start the application for debugging, I get the following exception

```
SourceMaps.getMapForGeneratedPath: exception while processing path: 
http://localhost:4000/js/dll.vendors.js, sourcemap: index.js.map
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

and all the break point became grey with message:

> Unverified break point, break point ignored because generated code not 
>   found (source map problem?)

It's clear that it's related to source map. My project using webpack to built and the final file is dll.vender.js.

I can share the configuration if you want to know more. Really appreciate your help so that I can finally run line by line through the code.

Thanks